# Increase the efficiency of the Sqldf operator in R by alternative ways

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, dataframe, sqldf

I'm dealing with a dataset with has data at a day level (one row for one day) - with data for a product (that is being advertised) on whether it is being seen by the user or if an action is being taken.

Before running my analysis on this data set in R - i'm want to filter the data in such a way i filter out all the days where the difference of number of times product is seen and number of times the action is being taken is 2 and views are 3. 
I was able to do this via an SQL statement in R - First i filter out the required days using the sqldf package like:

```
 filterd_days = sqldf(select day, count(views) as seen, count(action) 
as actions from subset_data group by day  
having (count(views) - count(action) = 2) and count(views) = 3)
```

I then join this dataset (o/p of the SQL) with the original one to filter the original data set with the required dates.

```
data_new = data[data$day %in% filter_days$day,]
```

But this is taking a close to 5 minutes for each dataset to execute and as this needs to run every day wondering if there's a faster way to execute this operation and get the same o/p.

Comment: Providing sample input data and expected output data will be most helpful in getting working answer.

Comment: Try adding an index.  See the sqldf github page for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try using data.table instead of data.frame

Assumption:

I am assuming the dataset appears like this:

```
>t
          day views action
1: 01/01/2010     1      1
2: 01/01/2010     1      0
3: 01/01/2010     1      0
4: 02/01/2010     1      1
5: 02/01/2010     1      1
```

You will get the required subset if you execute this command:

```
t[,if (sum(views) - sum(action) == 2 & sum(views) == 3) .SD,by=day]
```

The Output will be:

```
          day views action
1: 01/01/2010     1      1
2: 01/01/2010     1      0
3: 01/01/2010     1      0
```

Comment: @PratyushTallapragada Have you installed "data.table" package? If you are not aware about "data.table", please go through the tutorial for "data.table" first. It is somewhat different from data.frame.

Comment: Haven't used it before. Did go through the basic syntax and now - did try that on my file and it gave me 0 rows. I see that you've edited your solution to include .SD -  i see that its a data frame related parameter used in data table - could you tell me what is its use and why should we use this in this case ?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also - the warnings i'm getting before the o/p is 0 is : 
"In if ((count(views) - count(action)) ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Not sure what this means. Any idea ?

Comment: @PratyushTallapragada As far as .SD is concerned, its use is mentioned in the help for data.table. You can refer to that by ?data.table.

Comment: Also, the warning that you are getting is because of wrong parentheses deployment. Please run the query mentioned in the answer.